# Custom Advancements and Functions 1.13.2

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-data-packs

I'm setting up a new server, and would like to have some custom Advancements.

I was thinking of using these as a way to start new players out with some basics...as they go through the spawn room, they would trigger Advancements that would run Functions to give them some items:

- wooden axe
- wooden pick
- wooden sword
- white bed
- some food
- leather armor...

Nothing ground shaking, but should allow for a slightly easier start.

I tried using the [Advancements Generator here](https://advancements.thedestruc7i0n.ca/) and using location ranges as the criteria, but they don't seem to be working.

Now I'm trying to use command blocks and pressure plates...but I can't get the correct commands to either grant the Advancement to the player stepping on the pressure plate...or the Function to gift the items to the player stepping on the pressure plate.

I've tried using the `@p` selector but that isn't working... `give @p item amount`

Have also tried `execute as @s run give @p...` but that isn't working either.

Do I have to somehow anchor the command to a location?  I would have thought that the command block's location would be used by default...maybe it isn't though,

Thanks

**Update:**

If I run axe.mcfunction which has `give @s wooden_axe 1`...it works from chat

However, some of the functions aren't being recognized, and that is obviously the issue...like

```
give @s leatherhelmet 1 28 {display:{color:1476153,Name:Newb},ench:[{id:0,lvl:1},{id:3,lvl:1},{id:4,lvl:1}]}
```

...even when run in chat returns an error of `Error: Player not found`.  It only works when I type in the actual username...no variables are working...@s, @p, @a won't work...

**Update 2**

After playing around some more...

```
/give @s leatherhelmet 1 28 {display: {Name: "Newb", color: 1476153}}
```

works with the playername...every time...still doesn't work with the variable.

**Update 3**

I now have the Advancements being granted correctly...and most of the functions to give items...the only one that isn't working is the one to give colored armor...

I got the command blocks to give the items by using `execute as @p run function ...` and the functions use `give @p item count`

Comment: Does the function work when executed from chat?

Comment: Some do...I will update.

Comment: That is very weird. There's a syntax error in your leather helmet command, but it's later than the player. Are you sure that you used that exact command? Did you copy it in Minecraft and paste it in here? Please don't re-type it.

Comment: Yeah, copy and pasted

Comment: That command works if I put my name in...so I guess the syntax error isn't big enough to throw an error...but what is it?

Comment: There's no way that command runs with a name instead of `@s`, because just `leatherhelmet 1 28` already contains two syntax errors. Also, there's just one severity category of errors: Doesn't run. Not sure what you mean with "big enough".

Comment: It does, but it gave me a plain leatherhelmet with half durability this time...And there may be only 1 severity in Minecraft, but most apps have like three levels...info, warn,error

Comment: Which Minecraft version are you in?

Comment: I'm in 1.13.2 now.

Comment: Not sure if this helps anyone but here is the [location criteria](https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Advancements/List_of_triggers#minecraft:location).

Answer (score 1):

According to the error messages, it seemed that you are using Essentials? If you are not, the following will not ever be correct.

Use `minecraft:give` instead of `give`, since Essentials give command does not recognize selectors.

Answer (score 0):

So I need to do this too for my server but I already have a answer

/execute @a ~~~{Inventory:[{id:”Minecraft:(put desired item here)”}]} then whenever a new player joins the server, use this command and put their name at the end /testfor(newbie’s name here) then if it’s them, have a command that makes the achievement happen,